# Query Spring собственный запрос из двух таблиц

Tags: java, spring, запрос, jpa

Сам запрос работает из консоли и выдает корректный результат, но как только я этот запрос скопировал в аннотацию @Query он перестал понимать переменные, как бы я их не написал (даже через полный путь)

```
@Query (value = "select  new  analytics77j.analytics77j.dto.IncomingRequestByUtmDTO (name, whatsapp, utm_source)" +
        "from client\n" +
        "inner join incoming_request\n" +
        "on client.id = incoming_request.client_id;")
```

Запрос который работает

```
select analytics.public.client.name, analytics.public.client.whatsapp, analytics.public.incoming_request.utm_source
from client
inner join incoming_request
on client.id = incoming_request.client_id;
```

Ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это статический анализатор идеи ругается? Похоже не сконфигурена конфигурация хибернейта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переменные надо указывать с двоеточием

```
@Query (value = "select  new  analytics77j.analytics77j.dto.IncomingRequestByUtmDTO (:name, :whatsapp, :utm_source) " +
            "from client " +
            "inner join incoming_request " +
            "on client.id = incoming_request.client_id")
```